# VS Code : .net doesn't exist in "select debugger"

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

When I try to debug C# or F# or create `launch.json`, the .NET I installed does not appear in "Select debugger".

In C#, if I press Yes on "Required assets to build and debug are missing from 'tutorial_vscodedotnet'. Add them?" and press Yes, a ".vscode folder" will be created and <kbd>F5</kbd> will work.

If I don't press Yes and do "create a launch.json File", ".net Framework 4.x (Windows only)" appears.

In fact, there was one time on each computer when I pressed <kbd>F5</kbd> and ".NET 5+ and .NET Core" showed up.

That came up when I re-installed the environment from scratch, but it never showed up again.

I've rebooted, reinstalled extensions, but that didn't work.

I tried it on several computers and the same thing happened. The `dotnet` command works fine.

I ask this question because I have looked into it and you guys don't seem to have stumbled on this issue.

I'm a beginner so it is possible that I haven't done the basics.

VS Code extensions:

- C#
- Ionide for F#

[F# halloworld](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Qpqo.png)

[Run and Debug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UJGqg.png)

[dotnet --info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NS5dn.png)

### postscript

I disabled the extension "Ionide for F#" and ".NET 5+ and .NET Core" appeared!

I think this is the solution for C#, but I need this extension for F#, right?

Is it possible to solve the problem with "Ionide for F#" enabled?(or do I not need "Ionide for F#"?)